# Is there a standard for ISO standard naming?

Tags: iso

For example, "ISO/TS 16952-1:2006".

What is the meaning of "/", "-", and ":"?

Does the numbers follow a convention or they're just random generated numbers?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question within the scope defined by the Help Center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know why getting down voted. But I finally found the answer.

There is no ISO standard for ISO standard naming, but I got an official answer from email.

The "/" serves to separate the short name of organization and an acronym. For example "ISO/TS" indicates that the document is an ISO Technical Specification. A Technical Specification is one of the deliverables available from ISO, the complete list of deliverables via the following link:

http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm

Another case of the use of the "/" is to indicate a standard developed jointly with another organization such as the IEC (International Electrotechnical Commission), ISO/IEC.

The "-" means "Part" and is used in the references of multi-part standards. For example ISO 14644-1, indicates Part 1 of ISO 14644.

At the end of each reference number of a published standard, the ":" is used to separate the reference number from the year of publication. For example, ISO 9001:2015.

The numbering of ISO standards has no real meaning, except to identify them. Usually they are numbered in a progressive order, where newer standards have higher numbers. Sometimes some technical committees (the committees that develop the standards) reserve a certain range of numbers for their standards and that's why standards related to certain subjects (like Quality Management) may have similar numbers even if released in different stages. In any case, there is no particular meaning in the number chosen for an ISO standard.

Comment: Thanks for sharing-- I found that helpful.